# I'm struggling with the syntax of a min/max range variable using Splashkit

Tags: c++, syntax

I'm brand new to coding and have started with C++. I've just finished my hello world and a few other simple tasks and this is my first decent sized task. I have finished around 90% of it but I am struggling with the syntax.

I have a circle which can move up, down, left and right, it changes color, as does the background. It is also able to change the size using minus and equals.

THE PROBLEM:
Currently the radius is set via user input from the terminal which is a task requirement. I now need to have the radius only be allowed between 10 and 200.

I have been working on it for hours and I am furhter away now then when I started lol. I have the under < 10 part working and couldn't get the > 200 part correct. Now they both throw off errors.

Please help a noob on the start of his coding adventure :)

```
 #include "splashkit.h"

 // #define RADIUS 50
 #define MIN_RANGE 10
 #define MAX_RANGE 200

 string read_string(string prompt)
 {
 string result;
 write(prompt);
 result = read_line();

 return result;
 }

 int main()
 
 {
 double x;
 double y;
 color circle_color = COLOR_GREEN;
 color screen_color = COLOR_WHITE;
 int radius;
 string line;
 radius = 32;


 while (radius <= MIN_RANGE) + (radius >= MAX_RANGE);

 {
 line = read_string("Enter the starting Radius of the Circle: ");
 radius = convert_to_double(line);

 if (radius < MIN_RANGE)
 {
 write("Sorry. Please select a radius between 10 and 200! ");
 }

 else if (radius > MAX_RANGE)
 {
 write("Sorry. Please select a radius between 10 and 200! ");
 }
 else
 {
 open_window("Circle Mover by James Jones", 800, 600);

 x = screen_width() /2;
 y = screen_height() /2;

 }
 }


 while( not quit_requested() )
 {
 process_events();


 if ( key_typed ( SPACE_KEY ))
 {
 screen_color = random_color();
 }

 if ( key_typed ( C_KEY ))
 {
 circle_color = random_color();
 }

 if ( key_down(RIGHT_KEY) )
 {
 x = x + 3;
 }

 if ( key_down(LEFT_KEY) )
 {
 x -= 3;
 }

 if ( key_down(DOWN_KEY) )
 {
 y = y + 3;
 }

 if ( key_down(UP_KEY) )
 {
 y -= 3;
 }

 if ( key_down(EQUALS_KEY) )
 {
 radius = radius + 1;
 }

 if ( key_down(MINUS_KEY) )
 {
 radius = radius - 1;
 }


 if ( x + radius > screen_width() )
 {
 x = screen_width() - radius;
 }

 if ( x - radius < 0 )

 {
 x = radius;
 }
 if ( y + radius > screen_height() )
 {
 y = screen_height() - radius;
 }

 if ( y - radius < 0 )
 {
 y = radius;
 }

 clear_screen(screen_color);
 fill_circle(circle_color, x, y, radius);
 refresh_screen(60);



 }
 return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is with this line

```cpp
 while (radius <= MIN_RANGE) + (radius >= MAX_RANGE);
```

i suggest you replace it with

```cpp
while ((radius <= MIN_RANGE) and (radius >= MAX_RANGE))
```

and make sure you delete the semicolon `;` in front of the while loop. because it represents an empty statement. so for example

```cpp
while(1<2);
```

is an infinite while loop that executes that empty statement (which means executes nothing) in every iteration